# Objective C: Getting ONLY the addess of an object

Tags: ios, debugging

When I use

```
NSLog("view = %@", view)
```

I will get something like that as result:

```
UIImageView: 0x79908a0; frame = (0 0; 320 548); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7969370>; layer = <CALayer: 0x79900f0>
```

But I only what the address of the view:

```
UIImageView: 0x79908a0
```

Is there a possibility to handle that?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `%p` format (which prints the contents of any pointer in `0x...` format):

```
NSLog("view = %p", view)
// Output: view = 0x79908a0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *obj = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
NSString *addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p", obj];
NSLog(@"Address is = %@",addr);
```

Use the `%p` formatter to get the address of an object. Result will be String Starting with `0x` hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

NSString:description is what is called on a class when you pass an instance of it into NSLog like this, so you could override that to produce whatever you like.

If you really really want to do this, you could override UIView description class in a category and ignore the warnings like so:

NOTE: THIS BEHAVIOUR IS UNDEFINED: "If the name of a method declared in a category is the same as a method in the original class ... the behavior is undefined as to which method implementation is used at runtime". SO USE AT YOUR OWN RISK!

```
@interface UIView (Overide)
@end

@implementation UIView (Overide)

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"
- (NSString *) description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %p", NSStringFromClass(self.class), self];
}
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

@end
```

You would just need to import this into your precompile header (.pch) file and it would take effect immediately over your whole project.

Comment: But have a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW4: *"If the name of a method declared in a category is the same as a method in the original class ... the behavior is undefined as to which method implementation is used at runtime."*

Comment: Fair enough... I didn't think it was a good idea, I just said 'if you really really want to do this'.... If it is undefined.. then that would imply at some point if i execute this test enough, then the other implementation would be called. However, the category version always seems to be called.

Comment: ... you could always swizzle if are determined for this to work. Again, not something i recommend, but an alternative solution.